# Using a template matching correlation image to extract lines

Tags: ecognition, template, correlation

[image: Correlation image with identified points using template matching]

I need to measure the length of the rows which are visible in the images. I have used template matching with a portion of the row as the template.

Along a row, there will be matches which are identified as points, as seen in this image.

Now I am unsure which direction to take this approach this problem

1) If I am able to constrain the direction, I could try to draw best-fit lines and clip the lines with a manually digitized boundary

2) Use the correlation image instead to generate segments and measure the lengths of the segment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "line extraction" to detect the lines. Here's a tutorial tutorial with sample dataset. http://community.ecognition.com/home/line-extraction